# Forgotten Sci-fi novel title - class system and motorbike racing

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading a sci-fi book in the late 90s/early 2000s which I really enjoyed, but can't remember the title.

It was set in an alternate future where people are tested at the end of school and divided into classes – 'Ests' for most, 'Alphas' a scientist class for those who get 100%, and those who fail become another class, the name of which I've forgotten. The protagonist becomes an Alpha before running away to join the underclass, where he helps a prostitute, takes up motorbike racing and falls in love with a fellow racer. Memory gets a bit hazy as to the ending, but they go on to bring down the system and it involves a sentient computer with an obsession with the film [Casablanca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casablanca_(film)).

I think the title contains a number and refers to the career track of motorbike racing and I'd guess it was written late 80s/early 90s.

Comment: Was it written on late 90s/early 2000s or late 80s/early 90s? You mention both

Comment: Sounds like Brave New World but with motorbikes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sci-fi dystopian book about a boy who rides a motorcycle](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52553/sci-fi-dystopian-book-about-a-boy-who-rides-a-motorcycle)

Comment: Possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/184134/anyone-tell-me-the-name-of-this-half-remembered-sci-fi-story-about-a-genius-teab (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 10):

This has got to be [Futuretrack-5](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Futuretrack-5-Robert-Westall/dp/0007126913), by [Robert Westall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Westall).

**It was set in an alternate future where people are tested at the end
of school and divided into classes - 'Ests' for most, 'Alphas' a scientist class for those who get 100%, and those who fail become another class, the name of which I've forgotten.**

Quoting from HarperCollins' blurb on the recent [reissue](http://www.harpercollins.co.uk/titles/9780007126910/futuretrack-5-robert-westall):

> A fantasy of the near future in which Britain is divided into Zones
>   and castes to which men and women are pitilessly allocated at the end
>   of their schooling. Whether crazed proles in the Unnem zones, smug
>   pampered bourgeois Ests or arrogant Techs

**The protagonist becomes an Alpha**

And now quoting from [a review on readingmatters](http://www.readingmatters.co.uk/review/futuretrack-5):

> Henry Kitson is a very bright boy. He does so well in his final exams
>   that he finds himself elevated from mere Establishment. He becomes a
>   'Tech'.

**before running away to join the underclass**

> He makes a spur of the moment decision to slip through the Wire on a
>   temporary pass and see what life is really like for the Unnems.

**it involves a sentient computer**

(Back to the HarperCollins blurb):

> all are ultimately pawns of the computer that governs it all.

**I think the title contains a number and refers to the career track of motorbike racing**

Check! And the cover of the original Puffin edition might look familiar:

[image: the cover of the original Puffin edition (from Goodreads)]

**I'd guess it was written late 80s/early 90s.**

1983, so certainly around by then.